# arrayfun with function with inputs of different dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, cuda, gpu, large-data

I'm trying to create a matrix that contains the averages of the kxk submatrices of a larger nxn matrix, where n is divisible by k. I can accomplish this fairly efficiently with something like this

```
mat = mat2cell(mat, k*ones(1,n/k), k*ones(1,n/k))
mat = cellfun(@mean,mat,'UniformOutput',false);
mat = cellfun(@mean,mat,'UniformOutput',false); %repeated to collapse cells to 1x1
mat = cell2mat(mat)
```

However, since I have a very large amount of data all in very large matrices, repeating this process can still take a long time even on a cluster, and combining the matrices is not an option due to memory limitations. I'm wondering if it's possible to rewrite this code using `arrayfun` instead so I can utilize its GPU capability (as GPU cannot process cell arrays), but I'm running into problems since the helper function

```
function avg = blockavg(mat,i,j,k)
i1 = (i-1)*k+1;
i2 = i*k;
j1 = (j-1)*k+1;
j2 = j*k
avg = mean(mean(mat(i1:i2,j1:j2)));
end
```

calls for two broadcast variables `mat`, an nxn matrix, and `k`, a scalar, and these are not array inputs when plugged into `arrayfun`. When running

```
ii = 1:(n/k);
jj = 1:(n/k);
matavg = arrayfun(@blockavg,mat,ii,jj,k)
```

An error message returns stating that input arguments must be arrays of the same size and shape, as only `ii` and `jj` are the array inputs, while `mat` and `k` do not vary across elements. I'm not quite sure how to work around this issue, or even if this type of operation is possible at all for `arrayfun`. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To fix your input size issue, which probably results in a slower solution, you have to use the standard pattern for constants. Define an anonymous function containing these constants: `matavg = arrayfun(@(ii,jj)(blockavg(mat,ii,jj,k)),mat,ii,jj,k)`. But I think this solution is slower that the two versions I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another nice possibility without using the image processing toolbox:

```
squeeze(mean(mean(reshape(X,k,n/k,k,n/k),1),3))
```

This code reshapes the matrix in a way, that each block can be accessed by Y(a,:,b,:), which means they have identical first and third dimension index. Then mean is applied to first and third dimension, finally singleton dimensions are removed to get a 2d-result.

Comment: Thanks! This cut my run time by about a half. Thanks for the other pointers, too, really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is exactly what `blockproc` from the image processing toolbox provides:

```
blockproc(X,[k k],@(x)(mean(mean(x.data))))
```

To speed up, you may try setting the `UseParallel`-parameter.